# display option value on multiple select

Tags: jsp, metronic

How can I display value with option of multiple select.

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" name="my_multi_select1[]">
    <s:iterator value="supplierModelList" var="item" >
         <option>
            <s:property value="%{item.suppGroupId}"/>
         </option>
     </s:iterator>
    </select>
```

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: I found solution. I just need to change s:property like this.           <s:property value="#item.supplierId" /> .